# Configuring libgraph : SDL_Image not found even though it is installed

Tags: linux, sdl, sdl-image

I got to install libgraph (1.0.1) in my Crunchbang (Debian/7.7) system.
Of course you have some dependencies before that. SDL_Image was downloaded and installed  from source successfully. I compiled a C++ program with SDL headers to test it out..ran perfectly.
However, while running `./configure` it still throws :

```
checking SDL  ==>  SDL_image library... configure: error: *** 
: *** SDL_image not found
```

The SDL and SDL_image packages are installed.

```
devesh@crunchbang:~/downloads/libgraph-1.0.1$ dpkg --get-selections | grep sdl
libsdl-image1.2:amd64               install
libsdl1.2-dev                       install
libsdl1.2debian:amd64               install
libsdl1.2debian:i386                install
```

From other questions, it could be that SDL_image file's may be in a different directory, other than the 'default' ones. But SDL was detected, and they're installed in the same place.
What's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one look in the README file in the libgraph directory gives me this:

```
You need to have the following installed : 
SDL-x.x.x.rpm               -- the main SDL library
SDL-devel-x.x.x.rpm         -- the developer package
SDL_image-x.x.x.rpm         -- image library for fonts
SDL_image-devel-x.x.x.rpm   -- image library developer
```

I installed **libsdl1.2-dev** and *voila*!
**SDL_Image** detected.
Only to stumble upon another bunch of packages not installed :-P.
(**guile** and what not)
But got the problem at hand!
Thanks